# The "history" tag needs a Wiki description and a possible cleaning

Tags: discussion, tags

When reviewing [an edit suggestion for the question *Why do most browsers store browsing history by default?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/67646) where someone wanted to remove the [history](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag from the question, I saw that there is apparently a misunderstanding about what the [history](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag is for exactly:

- Some questions use this tag to ask about historical subjects, for instance [*What was so dangerous about PGP that its creator was charged in court for it?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/55023/32746) or [*Why has the NSA had a hand in deciding on encryption standards?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/103731/32746) (it may be worth noting that these are by far the two most upvoted questions with this tag),
- Some other questions use this tag to ask about the history and logs stored by various systems, for instance [*What does my iPhone see/track when connected to my macbook PC?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/99866/32746) or [*How are logs stored with ISP?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/62271/32746) (the reviewed question obviously comes here).

I think that the role of this tag should be clarified and this tag removed from the questions where it is not appropriate. However, I raise the issue here because both uses seem legit and make sense as per this site topic. So I think a common discussion might be more appropriate before doing anything.

My current understanding and a quick check leads me to such suggestion:

1. Merge the [historical](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical) and [history](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) to keep only one of them (while less used, the former may have a clearer wording than the latter one?),
2. Update the Wiki for the kept tag to dedicate it to historical questions, and clearly redirect the questions pertaining to history and logs kept by various systems to [logging](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging) (if the tag name by itself may lead to confusion, a clear warning message like the one used for [security-theater](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security-theater) may be needed),
3. Update the [logging](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logging) tag description to clearly include questions about various software history.

Comment: I agree, and went ahead and merged the tags into [tag:historical] - as you say, less ambiguous. (I am still ambivalent on even needing that tag at all, but whatever...). Please do go through the tag to see if there are any that should be changed to [logging], or removed altogether (I did a whole bunch already).

Comment: logging could be seen from different perspectives, I agree in general. Maybe we could fork logging into logging/logged?